# How can I upload csv file to S3 by containing '/' url by aws-sdk/lib-storage.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload csv file by [aws-sdk/lib-storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html#upload)

When I specify S3 url(ex. https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee) to Bucket property of params, error massage `InvalidBucketName: Bucket name shouldn't contain '/'` occurred.

How can I specify url containing '/'?

・code

```
      const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
        client: new S3Client({
          region: 'us-east-1',
          credentials
        }),
        params: {
          Bucket:
            'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee,
          Key: file.name,
          Body: file
        },
        leavePartsOnError: false
      })
```

When I specify only Bucket Name, no containing '/', upload was succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Bucket' parameter just give the bucket name and in the 'Key' give the path and file name. And also you don't need to give 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' in the 'Bucket' parameter. So, your code would be like this:

```
const parallelUploads3 = new Upload({
        client: new S3Client({
          region: 'us-east-1',
          credentials
        }),
        params: {
          Bucket: <Bucket Name>,
          Key: <File Path>/file.name,
          Body: file
        },
        leavePartsOnError: false
      })
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer!